# Concatenation of columns with no fixed number of columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to concatenate a bunch of columns in SQL.

The problem is that there is no set number of columns and therefore could have to concatenate 18 columns together in one run and 30 the next.

The table structures look like :

**concatbase**:

```
ID  | planprefix | plannumber | ConcatField_1 | ConcatField_2 | ConcatField_3 | ....
----+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+ ....
1   |   p        | 11         | 100-150       | 300           | 302           | ....
1   |   P        | 111        | 101           | NULL          | NULL          | ....
1   |   P        | 2222       | 600-908       | 1010          | NULL          | ....
4   |   D        | 33333      | 400-406       | NULL          | NULL          | ....
5   |   D        | 444444     | 300           | NULL          | NULL          | ....
6   |   p        | 19         | 200           | 300-308       | 400           | ....
```

Table **RPD_STAGING** (and expected result given ID 1 sample data)

```
Rank    | ID        | semi_rp                   |
--------+-----------+---------------------------+
1       |   1       | 100-150 & 300 & 302 P11   |
2       |   1       | 101 P11                   |
3       |   1       | 608-908 & 1010 P2222      |
```

I am using this SQL statement to concatenate this together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyid ORDER BY plannumber) AS rank,
    propertyid,
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_1 IS NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber ELSE ConcatField_1 END +
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_2  IS NULL AND ConcatField_1  IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_2  is null and ConcatField_1  IS NULL then  '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_2 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_3  IS NULL AND ConcatField_2  IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_3  is null and ConcatField_2  IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_3 END +  
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_4  IS NULL AND ConcatField_3  IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' +  planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_4  is null and ConcatField_3  IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_4 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_5  IS NULL AND ConcatField_4  IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_5  is null and ConcatField_4  IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_5 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_6  IS NULL AND ConcatField_5  IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_6  is null and ConcatField_5  IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_6 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_7  IS NULL AND ConcatField_6  IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_7  is null and ConcatField_6  IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_7 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_8  IS NULL AND ConcatField_7  IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_8  is null and ConcatField_7  IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_8 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_9  IS NULL AND ConcatField_8  IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_9  is null and ConcatField_8  IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_9 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_10 IS NULL AND ConcatField_9  IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_10 is null and ConcatField_9  IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_10 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_11 IS NULL AND ConcatField_10 IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_11 is null and ConcatField_10 IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_11 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_12 IS NULL AND ConcatField_11 IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_12 is null and ConcatField_11 IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_12 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_13 IS NULL AND ConcatField_12 IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_13 is null and ConcatField_12 IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_13 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_14 IS NULL AND ConcatField_13 IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_14 is null and ConcatField_13 IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_14 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_15 IS NULL AND ConcatField_14 IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_15 is null and ConcatField_14 IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_15 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_16 IS NULL AND ConcatField_15 IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_16 is null and ConcatField_15 IS NULL then  '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_16 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_17 IS NULL AND ConcatField_16 IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_17 is null and ConcatField_16 IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_17 END + 
    CASE WHEN ConcatField_18 IS NULL AND ConcatField_17 IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_18 is null and ConcatField_17 IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_18 END AS semi_rpd  
INTO 
    #RPD_STAGING
FROM
    #concat_base
```

Can anyone assist me in creating a solution that could deal with any number of ConcatFields?

If possible I would like to stick to SQL, however if necessary I am open to using other tools. If you need any further information please let me know.

Comment: You can build a dynamic SQL query maybe. By concatenating SQL commands as string pieces for a final statement then execute it with sp_executesql command as shown in sample http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx

Comment: I am familiar with dynamic sql statements, however not sure exactly how to use them in this case. Could you give a quick example of how I could use it to write one for this problem?

Comment: You can query the SYS.TABLE_COLUMNS system view and search for the maximum number for field names like 'ConcatField_%'. When you have this information, you can add that many of following sql code fragment " CASE WHEN ConcatField_17 IS NULL AND ConcatField_16 IS NOT NULL THEN ' ' + planprefix + plannumber when ConcatField_17 is null and ConcatField_16 IS NULL then '' ELSE ' & ' + ConcatField_17 END +  "

Comment: @MatthewHancock . . . A table has a *fixed* number of columns.  I don't understand your data model, but you have a problem if the number of columns in a table can change.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better you use [`CONCAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) built-in SQL function than Case, because it can handle a null value. for example, you can use

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() OVER(
    PARTITION BY propertyid 
    ORDER BY 
      plannumber
  ) AS rank, 
  propertyid, 
  CONCAT(
    planprefix, plannumber, ConcatField_1, 
    ConcatField_2...
  ) INTO #RPD_STAGING
FROM 
  #concat_base
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know that Concat() would allow null values.

Do you know of a way to deal with no set number of fields? I guess I could write 100 concat fields, but if possible would like a way so in the event 101 are required it dosent fail or miss any data.

Comment: CONCAT() is handling ISNULL() and COALESCE() solutions in this case. Concatenating string and numeric values with "+" expression can cause syntax errors. So the solution can be using one of these functions.

Comment: @MatthewHancock You would need to know the columns in the parsing phase when you write the SQL query. So you would concat(col1,col2,...,coln) present in the table concat_base

Answer (score 0):

This code *should* allow to concatenate over an unknown number of columns starting with "ConcatField_" I am unable to correct/debug the code(I am not running SQL server), but all of the elements are here to allow dynamic concatenation across an unknown number of fields assuming they all start with ConcatField.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT DENSE_RANK() OVER(
    PARTITION BY propertyid 
    ORDER BY 
      plannumber
  ) AS rank, P,
  propertyid, 

  ) INTO #RPD_STAGING
FROM 
  #concat_base,
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONCAT(', ' , col.Name)
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS col            
   WHERE col like 'ConcatField*'
   FOR XML PATH('') ) AS P (Concat_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions, I ended up rewriting the whole thing.

Instead of generating an indefinite number of columns I did something like the following!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp,#temp2

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
ID INT
,Parcel int
,lot NVARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO #temp(ID, Parcel, lot)
VALUES
 (1,111 ,1 ),(1,111 ,2 ),(1,111 ,3 ),(2,1212,1 ),(2,1212,3 ),(2,1212,4 ),(3,1333,1 ),(3,1333,7 ),(4,5555,1 ),(4,5555,7 )
,(4,5544,1 ),(4,5544,2 ),(5,1809,1 ),(5,1809,2 ),(5,1809,3 ),(5,1809,5 ),(5,1810,6 ),(5,1810,7 ),(5,1810,8 )

SELECT ID,Parcel,
(SELECT lot + ',' 
FROM #temp p2
WHERE p1.ID = p2.ID
AND p1.Parcel = p2.Parcel
ORDER BY ID,Parcel
    FOR XML PATH ('')) AS Products
    INTO #temp2 FROM #temp p1 
GROUP BY p1.ID,p1.Parcel

SELECT * FROM #temp2
```